# Is there a way to check where from app is installed

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play, apk

In my project I want to know from what website or android market, my application has been downloaded and installed.

Now I see two ways:
1) Use mobile browser storage to save location
2) Generate application for each site in the system

Both of them enough for my project, but I want to know if there is another legal ways through Play market

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [Google Play Campaign Measurements](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns)

> Google Play Campaign Measurement allows you to see which campaigns and
>   traffic sources are sending users to download your app from the Google
>   Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

[`PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName(java.lang.String)) will give you the package name of the app which installed the app with the package name passed in as a `String`.

Comment: I can know only about installer, that is not the way to resolve my problem. I just want to pass some information to app before installation, ex: i downloaded it from example.com or example1.com

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple apk files, one for every distribution channel you have.

In your project, create a `config.json` which contains the information you want to know about the installation and current version of the installed apk file of your application. The contents of the file, varies based on the distribution channel. For example, for the version you want to upload to Google Play, it can contain :

```
{
    "channel" : "google-play-store",
    "campaign_name" : "fall 2016"
}
```

Now, when the user installs and runs your application for the first time, read this config.json and send this information to a remote webservice of your own, to collect statistics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but again I don't want to share my app in any way except Play Market. I just want to pass some info to app from the site that shared the link to market